# How do I make vue app load its js files and css files from a cdn?

Tags: vue.js

What I'm trying to do is make my vue ssa app load all its static files from a cdn instead from a server hosting it. I build the app using the command npm run build and modify the file index.html like this, I changed

```
src="/js/chunk-vendors.0704b531.js" to src="https://cdn.example.com/js/chunk-vendors.0704b531.js"
href="/css/app.c7158abb.css" to href="https://cdn.example.com/css/app.c7158abb.css"
```

(Could not change

```
src="/js/app.ee558821.js" to src="https://cdn.example.com/js/app.ee558821.js"
```

without causing an error. I'll explain later)

and I upload all the files in the dist folder including the index.html to a shared hosting server. I'm using bunny cdn and configured it to work with my domain. All works fine. However when I tried to include the file app.ee558821.js on the cdn (Issue I said I'll explain later)

```
src="/js/app.ee558821.js" to src="https://cdn.example.com/js/app.ee558821.js"
```

I got these error messages on the browser console

```
ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 245 failed.
(missing: https://example.com/https://cdn.example.com/js/245.e400d699.js)
```

What I can see in the browser console is that all the files viz 'chunk-vendors.0704b531.js', 'app.c7158abb.css' and 'app.ee558821.js' successfully load from the cdn but the all the other files 'app.ee558821.js' somehow called where getting the path wrong. Instead of the normal path like https://cdn.example.com, the path instead look like this https://example.com/https://cdn.example.com.

Now my question is how do I make my vue app loads all its static assets from a cdn?

This is the content of my vue.config.js file

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service');
module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  lintOnSave: false,
});
```

These are the contents of my dist folder

```
css
   some files here
js
   |114.b704aee6.js
   |245.e400d699.js
   |439.027f133c.js
   |623.76b80e83.js
   |724.ebcd23c0.js
   |app.ee558821.js
   |chunk-vendors.0704b531.js
favicon.ico
index.html
```

Thank you very much any help is greatly greatly appreciated. I recently taught myself how to code and this is my first question on stackoverflow.

Comment: Maybe better approach would be setting [publicPath](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath) conditionally for a production build

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Michal Levý for pointing me in the right direction. I changed the publicPath property to 'https://cdn.example.com/' and that fixed the problem.